# Manual tests work, but Collection Runner Fails

Tags: postman

I have a Postman collection with Tests that works as intended when run manually with a specific environment file. However, when I attempt to run the same collection in the Collection Runner with the same environment file, I get an error that stops the entire process: "Open DevTools for more info." No other information is given.

The DevTools reveals an error relating to the Tests I run at the end of the call. ("Cannot read property 'event_type' of null") [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cO2c.png)

What I'm wondering is, why is the Collection Runner throwing an error, when manually making a request works as intended? Is there something I'm missing with how Postman works, or is there something in my code that is causing this?